# I want my json to be stored in a string variable in my controller

Tags: json, angularjs, pagination

I have a JSON which i am getting from service I would like to use that json to be stored in my string variable.
So my pagination works.

```js
var app = angular.module('Techapp', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('ngTableCtrl', function ($scope, ngTableParams) {
    var data = [{ Technology: "Core JAVA", CourseType: "Training Plan", JobLevelPrefered: "JL 3+", ContactPerson: "Kavitha_arjun" },
                { Technology: "Core JAVA", CourseType: "Training Material", JobLevelPrefered: "JL 3+", ContactPerson: "Kavitha_arjun" },
                { Technology: "Core JAVA", CourseType: "Training Plan", JobLevelPrefered: "JL 3+", ContactPerson: "Shanthi_A" },
                { Technology: "Core JAVA", CourseType: "Training Material", JobLevelPrefered: "JL 3+", ContactPerson: "Kavitha_arjun" },
                { Technology: "Core JAVA", CourseType: "Training Material", JobLevelPrefered: "JL 3+", ContactPerson: "Muthumari_T" },
                { Technology: "Core JAVA", CourseType: "Checklists", JobLevelPrefered: "JL 3+", ContactPerson: "Kavitha_arjun" },
                { Technology: "Core JAVA", CourseType: "Training Plan", JobLevelPrefered: "JL 3+", ContactPerson: "Kavitha_arjun" },
                { Technology: "Core JAVA", CourseType: "Training Plan", JobLevelPrefered: "JL 3+", ContactPerson: "Kavitha_arjun" },
                { Technology: "Core JAVA", CourseType: "Training Material", JobLevelPrefered: "JL 3+", ContactPerson: "Vatsala_Agrawal" },
                { Technology: "Core JAVA", CourseType: "Training Plan", JobLevelPrefered: "JL 3+", ContactPerson: "Kavitha_arjun" },
                { Technology: "Core JAVA", CourseType: "Training Plan", JobLevelPrefered: "JL 3+", ContactPerson: "Kavitha_arjun" },
                { Technology: "Core JAVA", CourseType: "Training Material", JobLevelPrefered: "JL 3+", ContactPerson: "Selvam_K01" },
                { Technology: "Core JAVA", CourseType: "Checklists", JobLevelPrefered: "JL 3+", ContactPerson: "Kavitha_arjun" },
                { Technology: "Core JAVA", CourseType: "Training Plan", JobLevelPrefered: "JL 3+", ContactPerson: "Kavitha_arjun" }
               ];

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams(
    {
        page: 1, // show first page
        count: 5 // count per page
    },  
    {
        total: data.length, // length of data
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(),  params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });
});

app.controller('CertificationCtrl', function ($scope, ngTableParams, $http) {
    var url = "http://localhost:58402/Search.svc/abc/ListsJava/Certification";
    $http.get(url)
      .success(function (data) {
         var myjson = JSON.parse(data);
         $scope.Title = JSON.parse(myjson)
      });
    var data = [];
    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams(
    {
        page: 1, // show first page
        count: 5 // count per page
    }, 
    {
        total: data.length, // length of data
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
            $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });
});
```

Like in ng-TableCtrl json is in a string variable. So my pagination is working fine. But in my CertificationCtrl since i am getting my json from a service i am not able to apply pagination. Pls help

Thanks

like in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `http://localhost:58402/Search.svc/abc/ListsJava/Certification` is already returning your JSON data, can't you just call your pagination codes in your `success` callback like this:

```
app.controller('CertificationCtrl', function ($scope, ngTableParams, $http) {
  var url = "http://localhost:58402/Search.svc/abc/ListsJava/Certification";
  $http.get(url)
    .success(function (data) {
      $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams(
         {
           page: 1, // show first page
           count: 5 // count per page
         }, 
         {
           total: data.length, // length of data
           getData: function ($defer, params) {
             $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
         }
    });
  });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Refer live demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/7jeyvk1d/). Don't worry about line 1 to 10 in the Javascript section; I used that to set up the test data to be sent to jsfiddle echo service. Replace the `url` variable on line 11 with your URL.

Also, note that I am using `$http.post` for demonstration, and have also removed all your `JSON.parse()` codes.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply i have already tried this. But its not giving me the results. I am not sure why. Its not giving any error as well :S

Comment: Try add `console.log(data)` to your `success` callback to see what you're getting. I replaced all references to `data` within `$scope.tableParams` with `myjson`; maybe you don't need that.

Comment: Now its giving me error "Object doesn't support property or method 'settings'" What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log(data)` to your `success` callback? What do you get in the debugger console?

Comment: I can't tell without knowing which line is causing the error. Try replace `myjson` with `data`.

Comment: Also if i change it to data its givingme 42650 pages. I dont even have these many records

Comment: I am unsure how you end up with 42650 pages. I have added a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/7jeyvk1d/) to my answer. See if that helps you.

Comment: Yes even i am doing the same thing it seems my json is not returning in the proper format.I am using Sharepoint service to fetch my data as the back end is in sharepoint..Thanks for the answer anyway.:)

Comment: You can try to use a [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/) to check the validity of your data. Meanwhile, if you find the answer helpful, will you consider upvoting and accepting it? Thanks!